# Convert class implements ActionListener into thread

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, multiple-inheritance

I have a simple 2d game class which looks like:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private Timer timr;

    public Game(){
        //other stuff
        timr = new Timer(10, this);
        timr.start(); 
    }
    //other methods including ActionListener-related ones
}
```

And instead of using Timer() for the timing I want to run Game as a thread, how can I do that and keep the ActionListener functions?

Comment: You can implement multiple interfaces, implement Runnable. implements ActionLister, Runnable{}

Comment: It depends, what does the `ActionListener` actually do?  You may want to have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to see some of the issues with Swing and Threads

Comment: @MadProgrammer `ActionListener` gets keystrokes and moves the sprite around the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't tie up your UI with the other game components. You need to have a good separation of concerns. Consider having a class that holds a representation of all the things in your game, this is your game *state*. You UI should only concern itself with drawing the current game state. You game should run in a loop where it updates the game state, then renders it with the UI.

```
class Game() {

  World world; //holds state of things in game
  UI ui;
  long time;
  long elapsed; //number of ms since last update

  mainGameLoop() {

    time = System.currentTimeInMillis();

    while (gameRunning()) {
      elapsed = System.currentTimeInMillis() - time;
      time = System.currentTimeInMillis();
      world.update(elapsed); //updates game state
      ui.render(world);      //draws game state to screen
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  Doesn't exactly answer my question but it led me to a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

So as @arynaq commented, one can implement multiple times by just putting a comma before the next abstract class, then later insert the abstract methods.

```
class Foo extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable{
    //runnable methods
    public void run(){}

    //ActionListener methods
    public void actionPerformed(){}
}
```